# Is Gödels second incompleteness theorem provable within peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, peano-axioms, incompleteness, provability

All following notation and assumptions follow [Gödel's Theorems and Zermelo's Axioms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-52279-7) by Halbeisen and Krapf.

Exercise 11.4 c) states "Conclude that the Second Incompleteness Theorem is provable within PA."

As the Second Incompleteness Theorem is stated as $\text{PA} \not\vdash \neg \text{prv}(\lceil 0=1 \rceil)$, I interpret the stated conclusion as the statment $\text{PA} \vdash \neg \text{prv}(\lceil{\neg \text{prv} (\lceil{0=1}\rceil)\rceil}).$

I could not find a proof of this fact. However, I think I managed to prove the opposite. But since this directly contradicts the authors, I am not sure if I am correct.

My solution:

> Amongst others, recall the following from the book:
>
> - The axiom scheme $(L1)$: $\varphi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow \varphi)$
> - The tautology (G): $\vdash(\varphi\rightarrow \psi)\leftrightarrow(\neg\psi\rightarrow \neg\varphi)$.
> - Löb's Theorem states that if $\varphi$ is an $L_{\text{PA}}$-sentence, then $\text{PA}\vdash \text{prv}(\lceil \varphi \rceil) \rightarrow \varphi$ implies $\text{PA} \vdash \varphi$.
>
> We assume by contradiction that $\text{PA} \vdash \neg \text{prv}(\lceil{\neg \text{prv} (\lceil{0=1}\rceil)}\rceil)$. Then by (L1) and Modus Ponens we can derive  $$\text{PA} \vdash \text{prv}(\lceil{0=1}\rceil) \rightarrow \neg \text{prv}(\lceil{\neg \text{prv} (\lceil{0=1}\rceil)}\rceil)$$   or equivalently (by (G))
> $$\text{PA} \vdash \text{prv}(\lceil{\neg \text{prv} (\lceil{0=1}\rceil)}\rceil) \rightarrow \neg \text{prv}(\lceil{0=1}\rceil).$$
> But by Löb's Theorem we then obtain
> $\text{PA} \vdash \neg \text{prv}(\lceil{0=1}\rceil)$ which
> contradicts the Second Incompleteness Theorem.     Therefore, $\text{PA} \not\vdash \neg \text{prv}(\lceil{\neg \text{prv} (\lceil{0=1}\rceil)}\rceil)$, i.e. the Second Incompleteness Theorem
> is ***not*** provable within $\text{PA}$

Do you know of a way to prove the original statement (i.e. solve the exercise)? Do you see any mistake in my proof? Do you agree with me? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Goedels results can only be proven using a meta-theory , not within a specific theory as PA.

Comment: @Peter that is (in part) what I am trying to show and directly contradicts the book. So a bit more detail would be appreciated.

Comment: @Peter that’s nonsense. PA could be the metatheory.

Comment: The second incompleteness theorem says *if PA is consistent* then it doesn’t prove its own consistency so the arithmetized form of that would be $\sf Con(PA)\to\lnot prv_{PA}(\ulcorner Con(PA)\urcorner))$

Comment: You are quite correct that PA doesn’t prove $\sf\lnot prv_{PA}(\ulcorner Con_{PA}\urcorner).$ It can’t prove PA is consistent (unless it’s inconsistent!) so can’t prove that PA doesn’t prove anything. But that’s the wrong interpretation of “the second incompleteness theorem”.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In the book, the second incompleteness theorem is stated as $\text{PA} \not\vdash \neg \text{prv}(\lceil 0=1 \rceil)$. Since I am trying to solve an exercise from said book, I have to adhere to that form of the theorem.
Note that I am not showing the statement "PA doesn't prove its own consistency", but  "PA can't prove that it can't prove its own consistency".

Comment: @Peter That's not the issue at all; see my answer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The OP is right: the authors messed it up here.

Comment: @Lassadar My point was that since PA can’t prove its own consistency then of course it can’t prove that it can’t prove anything. Sorry, I didn’t look at the book, I just assumed incorrectly that you (not the authors of the book) were making this common error of forgetting that the theorems need to be viewed as contingent on consistency in systems that are too weak to prove consistency.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen A very reasonable assumption. I didn't trust myself either, hence my question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common confusion, and in particular **[Halbeisen/Krapf](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-52279-7) messed it up here** (either Exercise 11.4(c) or Theorem 11.1 needs to be rephrased). The same confusion happens around the first incompleteness theorem G1IT; since it's a little easier to state, I'll treat it first.

---

The **general-and-conditional** statement of G1IT is as follows:

> $(\star)\quad$ If $T$ is a consistent r.e. theory interpreting $\mathsf{Q}$ then $T$ is incomplete.

This is almost always what logicians mean when we refer to "the first incompleteness theorem." This **is provable** in $\mathsf{PA}$. On the other hand, the statement

> $(\dagger)\quad$ $\mathsf{PA}$ is incomplete

is **not provable** in $\mathsf{PA}$ (unless $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent of course). The point is that $(\dagger)$ is not actually an instance of $(\star)$; rather, it is an instance of $(\star)$ together with a further hypothesis, namely $\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$.

---

The same issue happens with G2IT. While the "general" second incompleteness theorem takes a bit more care to state (see e.g. Willard's self-verifying theories), the following moderately-general version is provable in $\mathsf{PA}$:

> $(\star\star)\quad$ If $T$ is a consistent r.e. extension of $\mathsf{PA}$, then $T\not\vdash\mathit{Con}(T)$.

As above, the following **is not** provable in $\mathsf{PA}$:

> $(\dagger\dagger)\quad$ $\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$.

But this is - again - not a contradiction, since the latter only follows from the former *in the further presence of* a hypothesis which $\mathsf{PA}$ (hopefully!) doesn't prove.

---

Tl;dr, when people say "The incompleteness theorems are provable in $\mathsf{PA}$" they're referring to the *conditional-and-general versions*, not the specific incompletenesses about $\mathsf{PA}$ itself. Getting back to the H/K book in question, the right exercise is to show $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash [{\color{red}{\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA})\rightarrow}} \mathsf{PA}\not\vdash\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA})]$$

(or "$\mathsf{PA}\vdash\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA})\rightarrow\neg\mathsf{prov}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\mathit{Con}(\mathsf{PA}))$" if we want to be a bit more careful about distinguishing $\vdash$ from its formalization within $\mathsf{PA}$).

Comment: Gödel's 2IT is a claim in the meta-theory that mixes meta-theory and theory.  It says that if $\text{PA}$ is consistent in the meta-theory, there is a number-theoretic sentence (in the language of arithmetic) that attempts to mimic provability in the meta-theory, but is inequivalent to it and has a tenuous connection to it, and that sentence is unprovable in the meta-theory from $\text{PA}$.  The sentence in the last paragraph does not have any mixing.  It is entirely 'in the theory'.  It doesn't say anything about a sub-theory.  How can it be an expression of G2IT in the theory?

Comment: I'm not saying it's false that G2IT can  be expressed in $\text{PA}$, just asking how that sentence can be a correct stating of it?

Comment: @ChadK I don't understand your question, to be honest. I think it might be worth asking a separate question about it rather than using the comment thread (since this limits your ability to clarify the question and my ability to respond in detail).

Comment: That said, I think I disagree with your "but is inequivalent to it" re: the arithmetized consistency statement vs. the metatheoretic consistency statement. They are *(under extremely mild)* assumptions indeed equivalent, in the following sense the latter is *true* iff the former is *satisfied in the standard model of arithmetic*. The disconnect isn't between arithmetized version and meta version but rather between provability in a fixed theory of interest and satisfaction in a particular model of interest. *(Normally we would just say "true in a model," but for clarity I'm using "satisfies.")*

Comment: In (**), Con(PA) should be Con(T).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the book contains an error and for the detailed explanation. I guess since consistency of PA is obtained earlier in the book they left it out as an assumption in the theorem. But then the exercise should be adjusted.